# stderr and stdout of ssh?

Tags: ssh, expect, output

I am not clear about the stdout and stderr of ssh because if I execute say :

```bash
ssh user@remotemachine_ip "some command"
```

I get the output instantly on the screen or may be some error

1. logged in with ssh
2. remote commands are executed on the remote machine
3. the output is displayed on the remote machine (stderr or stdout) which I can see.
   Then it comes back to local machine.

or

the output come back to the local machine's stdout and which can be appended to a file on local machine.

So if I have a for loop in local machine

```bash
for i in ip1 ip2
do
    ssh user@remotemachine_ip "some command" 
done
```

what is the best way for error redirection and is it dependent on for, while, until loops

what if instead of ssh I am using some expect script

```bash
expectscript.exp user@remotemachine_ip "some command"
```

Comment: Your question isn't very clear. What specifically are you trying to do? There's no single "best way", it depends on what you need.

Comment: i was really having problems with directing the output of ssh in a for loop for multiple ipaddress but i was getting the output only for the first ip(in case redirection is inside the for loop) or the last ip(in case redircetion is out side )

Comment: There's no redirection in the code you posted, so it's hard to tell what you're doing wrong. Post the code with the problem, don't just describe it in general terms.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`SSH` is a protocol that lets you login into the remote machine just like you would login on a local machine.

In a local machine if you run a login shell (say one of  `Ctrl + Alt + F1~6`), it starts a new shell for the user and the output (`stdout` and `stderr`) goes right on your monitor.

Now let's take a look at your SSH case, the steps are similar to last time with just one difference, instead of sending the output (again `stdout` and `stderr`) to the monitor, the server sends the data back to the machine from which you logged in - to the `SSH client`. The client runs in your local machine and hence just displays the same output on the local machine's monitor.

But in case if you were to redirect the `stdout` and/or `stderr` to a file, when you're in a shell on the remote machine, that file would be on the remote machine, since the actual program you're running is executed on the remote machine.

BTW `SSH` does more than just merely sending/receiving the data to/from the remote machine, it also encrypts the data and lot more.

Comment: thanks @Tux if possible,can you give on examples for redirection inside a loop for multiple ips.does loops matter because i had prolems with redirection for multiple ipaddress and output being appended to a log file so i wanted to understand how ssh works

Answer (score 4):

```bash
for ip in ip1 ip2
do
  ssh user@$ip "some command" > output.$ip 2>&1
done
```

will put the output in a separate file for each IP.

```bash
for ip in ip1 ip2
do
  ssh user@$ip "some command"
done > output 2>&1
```

will put all the output in a single file.

Answer (score 1):

> what is the best way for error redirection

If I focus into just stderr redirection, the following could be one of the solution:

```bash
for ip in ip1 ip2
do
  ssh user@$ip "some command" >output.$ip 2>output.$ip.err
done
```

ssh looks supports remote stdout to local stdout and remote stderr to local stderr so that the above script runs as I expect.

Answer (score 0):

If you put

```bash
ssh user@$ip "some command" >output.$ip 2>output.$ip.err
```

inside an **expect** script the redirection of `stdout` and `stderr` will be ignored (**expect** will intercept the redirected output.  Inside the **expect** script you can add **log_user 0** and invoke your script with `stdout` redirected and this will work (albeit `stderr` goes nowhere)